# How to remove all words matching a pattern, except certain words which I want to preserve?(they match the pattern)

Tags: python, regex, words

So I have a pattern I want to strip from a corpus of words, however there are certain words that match the pattern which I want to keep. I have a list of such words, and can remove all words matching the pattern.

But, how do I keep the words in the list, and remove any others matching the pattern?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far?

Comment: Yes I'll just start up the notebook. But, In the mean time What I'm doing is just usin `re.sub` to match words with `@` in them

Comment: What I want to is remove all such words, but keep some that match the pattern. I have a list of those

Comment: I'm doing this :
`def replace_in_str(string):`
    
`return ' '.join(re.sub("([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",string).split())`

and then simply, 
`tweets["Message"]=tweets["Message"].apply(replace_in_str)`

I picked up that substitution from SO, as well, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set intersection

```
import re
s = 'Philip Hammond under pressure after claiming that public sector workers are overpaid'
s1 = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  s).split()
```

Then you go for

```
d1 = ['Philip', 'Hammond']

print (set(s1).intersection(d1))
```

Finally

```
{'Philip', 'Hammond'}
```

Comment: I guess I misphrased the question. If we take the intersection of s1 and d1, I will keep the words common in d1,and s1. This would return an empty set when I've already substituted the patterns . A union would be give me the result I want.